# Find the third basis vectors

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, vector-analysis, vector-fields

There are two sets of basis vectors $\vec{a}_1$, $\vec{a}_2$ and $\vec{b}_1$, $\vec{b}_2$.
I want to find the third basis vectors which norm are minimum:
$$\vec{R}_1=a_{11}\vec{a}_1+a_{12}\vec{a}_2=b_{11}\vec{b}_1+b_{12}\vec{b}_2$$
$$\vec{R}_2=a_{21}\vec{a}_1+a_{22}\vec{a}_2=b_{21}\vec{b}_1+b_{22}\vec{b}_2$$

and $a_{11},a_{12},a_{21},a_{22},b_{11},b_{12},b_{21},b_{22}$ are all integers.

I don't have any idea

Comment: It may be that there don't exist any integers $a_{11},a_{12},b_{11},b_{12}$ such that $a_{11}a_1+a_{12}a_2=b_{11}b_1+b_{12}b_2$ (other than taking them all to be zero, but then you're not getting a basis).

Comment: $(1,0),(0,1)$ is a basis for ${\bf R}^2$, so is $(\pi,0),(0,\pi)$, but there are no integers $a,b,c,d$ such that $a(1,0)+b(0,1)=c(\pi,0)+d(0,\pi)$ (except $a=b=c=d=0$).

Comment: @Subhajit Yes, we can always find such. But they may not be integers.

Comment: Which norm? What space do they span?

Comment: So, Max, any thoughts on the comments?